# Understanding cluster state update

Tags: java, scala, akka, distributed-system, gossip

I'm reading [gossip akka cluster](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/common/cluster.html#Gossip) documentation and still have one little misunderstanding about gossip.

As said in [***this answer***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39445097/3663882), two nodes are gossiping about the value and then who seen this value. But this comes with some issue about convergence. Here's how I see this:

***S*** - is a seen set.

[image: cluster topology]

The issue is at some time, only **node 4** knows that convergence happened. node 1, 2 and 3 still think it does not. I'm interesting about how should node 4 deal with convergence?

Should it initiate a new gossip round that convergence happened? Or how can other nodes know about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodes 1-3 will still be gossiping (well, 3 probably already knows about convergence because it knows 4 has the value.) As they continue gossiping they will be exchanging notes on who has seen the value.

Node 4 (and 3 really), and all subsequent nodes knowing about convergence continue gossiping but without the random weighting mentioned in your other question. In the protocol section of your linked doc it says:

> While the cluster is in a converged state the gossiper only sends a small gossip status message containing the gossip version to the chosen node. As soon as there is a change to the cluster (meaning non-convergence) then it goes back to biased gossip again.

Comment: So, the bottom line is that gossiping always takes place. If a node observes current state as converged it sends small status messages. Once a node observed non-convergence it starts sending a "normal gossip messages" until it observes convergence again. Is that correct?